# Possible to update javascript object property from another object

Tags: javascript, object, appcelerator

Greetings,

I have been working on a custom namespace in appcelerator but have run into a problem updating global namespace variables from within certain Titanium objects.

I have a wrapper called "**myObj**", and inside of myObj is another object called "**globals**" which contains variables that are set and used throughout the namespace.

```
myObj.globals = {
    userBalance: null,
    userAuthenticated: false,
    deviceGeoActive: false
}
```

So I've created a custom wrapper for the geolocation module and inside of that wrapper is the standard *Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(e)* function and some custom stuff to be used with the app.

Inside of the Ti.Geolocation.getCurrent...(e) I check to see if location service is available on the device and has been authorized for the app. Then I want to update the **deviceGeoActive** object property in myObj.

```
Ti.Geolocation.getCurrent...(e){
    if (e.success){
        myObj.globals.deviceGeoActive = true
    }
}
```

This way I'll be able to check if the device is Geo enabled anywhere, anytime.

Why I believe it's failing (and this is a guess, I'm fairly new at javascipt) is because Ti is outside of the myObj namespace and therefore cant access it in this way.

Can anybody point me in the proper direction?

Thanks,

**Josey**

Comment: Does `Ti.Geolocation.getCurrent...(e)` get called before myObj is defined ?

Comment: tried debugging to see if it sees the object? how are you defining myObj ?

Comment: Yes, it sees the object. If I update deviceGeoActive from outside of Ti... it updates just fine.

var myObj = {};

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the whole point of the question the fact that you are NOT updating it ?

Comment: The problem is that I cant update it based on something that is returned inside of Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().

Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(e) will pass the property "success" to **e** if geolocation is available on the device so I'm trying to update myObj.globals.deviceGeoActive based on what is defined within Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().

myObj.globals.deviceGeoActive seems to be able to change from anywhere but inside of Ti.Geolocation

Comment: Let me reiterate myself. Tried debugging to see if `the scope Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` sees the object?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I just tested to see if `Ti.Geolocation` was even receiving myObj and it does not appear to be. Any tricks to remedy that?

Comment: are you defining your object inside of a closure? it seems it's not in the global namespace. You can try removing var from your variable definition.

Comment: No at `closure`. I removed the var but its behaving in exactly the same manner.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to do window.myObj in both cases to ensure proper scope. Let me know of the outcome of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Khez for helping get me to this point!

> The only solution I can think of is to do window.myObj in both cases to ensure proper scope. Let me know of the outcome of this - @khez

Titanium **Appcelerator** doesn't work inside of the window namespace but your suggestion did make me think to add **myObj** to the global **Ti** (or Titanium) namespace.

So in the beginning I had this:

```
var myObj = {}
```

But **myObj** was being ignored by **Ti**.

To add it to the global **Titanium** namespace I modified it like so:

```
Ti.myObj = {}
myObj = Ti.myObj;
```

This way any calls to myObj remain don't have to be changed to reference Ti.

This means that myObj is now a child of the parent (global) Ti namespace.

Thanks again Khez